# Trying to make a button after an import statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, button, import

I am trying to program something that reads in file data, stores specific information in an array, then exports that array to a different javascript file. In the javascript file, in which I import the array, I am trying to create a button that has text-based off of the array.

The problem I am having is that after I import the array and initialize the button, it will not appear. However, if I don't import anything and have the same code to initialize my button (but with me writing random stuff for the button's text), it works fine. Also, I am sure that the array is being exported/imported fine because if I use console.log(names[0]) in the file I export it to, it will output the correct value. To clarify, if I include the import statement, I do not get an error, but the button just will not appear on the Chrome tab that it should appear on.

My first javascript file (why.js):

```
import fs from 'fs';
let names = [];
var lines = fs.readFileSync('input.txt').toString().split("\n");
for(let line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
    let word = "";
    let info = 0;
    for(let ind = 0; ind < lines[line].length; ind++){
        word += (lines[line]).charAt(ind);
        if((lines[line]).charCodeAt(ind) < 32 || (lines[line]).charCodeAt(ind) > 122){
            info++;
            if(info == 1){
                names.push(word);
            }
            word = "";
        }
    }
}
export { names };
```

my second javascript file (buttons.js):

```
//if I don't include this line, the button will initialize and appear
import { names } from './why.js'

let button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'artichoke';
//i want it to be: button.innerHTML = names[0]; 
document.body.appendChild(button);
console.log(names[0]);
```

I'm not sure if this is important, but here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>something random here for now ig</h1>
    <script src="why.js"></script>
    <script src="buttons.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

TLDR: After I import an array from my first javascript file to another, I am unable to create any button at all (though the code runs without error), but if I don't import anything, the button is created fine and appears.

Thank you for reading, and I would appreciate any feedback or tips :)

Comment: Why are you accessing OS filesystem through browser? That is not secure for visitor (then, it is not possible) You're using browser javascript not NodeJS, remember it

Comment: @Hanz - it's OK, the code won't work in a browser - I'm sure there's errors in the browser console, which is why including that line prevents the button from "appearing"

Comment: @patheticradish - check your browser *developer* tools console - you'll see that you can't "import fs" in a browser - you're confusing server side nodejs with browser code

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get what you all are saying. I'm new to Javascript and HTML so I'm unfamiliar with how this language works, sorry. What do you mean by "OS filesystem through browser"? I'm just trying to figure out why my button won't initialize after an import statement.

Comment: @JaromandaX Where can I find my browser developer tools console?

Comment: browser developer tools are in your browser - usually brought up using the F12 key (it's browser dependant, you probably using Chrome, so F12 should work) - anyway, it's not how the language works, it's what the difference is between nodejs and a browser - while both languages are the same, nodejs is not the same as a browser

Comment: and, before you ask, there is no way to read the fielsystem in browser javascript - as that would be a MASSIVE security issue

Comment: My F12 key is increasing the volume though. I am using Chrome, but I still don't understand what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: I'm trying to create a program in which I can just copy and paste information from a Google Spreadsheet into a text file, then create buttons using that information. Do you know any better ways I can accomplish this, if not through file reading?

Comment: @JaromandaX I still don't understand why reading the file has anything to do with not being able to create a button after an import statement.

Comment: errors in javascript tend to stop things from happening - what error message do you see in the browser console now that you know about it

Comment: I use vscode so there's kind of two ways I run it. If I run the javascript file I get an error that says "let button = document.createElement('button');
             ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Comment: However, if I run the HTML file through Chrome, no errors appear but the button just doesn't appear.

Comment: `no errors appear` doubt it - you're not even loading the scripts as modules, so no way `import` isn't giving you an error in Chrome - e.g. ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module***

Comment: But I'm not getting a syntax error? If it helps, I included "    "type" : "module"," in my package.json file. The only error I can see I'm getting when I run the javascript file is the document not defined error, but normally when I run the HTML file it doesnt matter.